# How I can select static dropDown box options from previous stored value at the time of Edit Record in Yii

Tags: php, yii, dropdownbox

I am using Static Values dropDown for insert data into database in Yii Form

This is my Source Code for insert static values

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'USER_TYPE',
  array(
    "C"=>"Client",
    "B"=>"Basic User",
    "A"=>"Administrator",
    "S"=>"Super Administrator"
  )
);
```

at the time of add or update its work fine.

Problem is this **How I can select static dropDown box options from previous stored value at the time of Edit Record.**

I have tried to find it solution. But no suitable help found

Comment: USER_TYPE is model variable or table field?

Comment: I have use same convention in MODEL class and Database Field name

Comment: field name is in upper case?

Comment: Yes. Exactly copy is the field name and model attribute name. Both are uppercase and both contains _ symbol.

Comment: If i will use textField instead of dropDown then it works fine. in both cases, Save Record and Update Record

Comment: ok. what is the value you have in this field in table?